# What is the best approach to refresh table body using on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, asynchronous

I am refreshing a table on button click. This approach is getting duplication of data on continuous clicks. Tried suggestions, jQuery remove(), empty() , html(), load location href #id > * like wise. Can anybody help in choosing best way.Table data is duplicating on 3 or more button clicks. The table getting loaded via appending, and flags are passed and getting td data

```
    //my function to call data
    function PharmacyChart(flag, Start_date, End_time) {
                $("div#spinner").fadeIn("fast");
                spinnerVisible = true;

                //For Local purchase Barchart
                var options = {
                    legend: { position: 'none' },
                    'height': '300',
                };
    //ajax call to get data starts
     $.ajax({

                    url: "" + Appsetting + "/Pharmacydashboard_V1/Pharmacy",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: { "Flag": flag, "startdate": Start_date, "enddate": End_time },
                    success: function (data) {

                        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    //.... relative code
    });//chart method closed

            $(document).on('click','.refreshid', function () {
        //table appending
                            for (var i = 0; i < valuesfortable.length; i++) {

                                tr = $('<tr/>');
                                tr.append("<td class='col-xs-4 border-left'>" + valuesfortable[i]["monthandyear"] + "</td>");
                                tr.append("<td class='col-xs-4'>" + valuesfortable[i]["NUMERATOR"] + "</td>");
                                tr.append("<td class='col-xs-4 border-right'>" + valuesfortable[i]["DENOMINATOR"] + "</td>");
                                $('#tableindex').append(tr);
                            }                   
         //$("#tbody tr").html("");
                           // $("#tableindex tbody").empty();
                      //   $("#tbody").load("location.html #tbody");
                           // $('#tableindex').parents('tr').remove();
                            //   $("#tbody").load(location.href +" #tbody > *");
                            //$("#tableindex tbody").remove();
                            $('#tableindex tbody').remove('tr');
            //This is method getting data.
            myChart(flag, start_date, end_date);
            });
});

            <!-- my html code -->

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-justified" id="tabControlsPharmacy" role="tablist">
                                            <li class="active tabchange" id="tablocalpurchase" tabindex="1"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu">Local purchase</a></li>
                                            <li class="tabchange" id="tabdishonoured" tabindex="2"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Dishonoured prescriptions</a></li>
                                            <li class="tabchange" id="tabstockout" tabindex="3"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Stock-out</a></li>
                                            <li class="tabchange" id="tabvariation" tabindex="4"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Variation in procurement process</a></li>
                                            <li class="tabchange" id="tabRejectedGRN" tabindex="5"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Rejected before GRN</a></li>
                                            <li class="tabchange" id="tabstats" tabindex="6"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu5">Pharmacy stats</a></li>
                                            <li class="pull-right"><a data-toggle="tooltip" href="##" id="" class="li_ic refreshid" title="Refresh" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-refresh" style="font-size:13px;"></i> </a></li>
                                            <li class="pull-right"><a data-toggle="tooltip" href="##" class="li_ic" id="filterid" title="Filter" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-filter" style="font-size:13px;"></i> </a></li>
                                        </ul>

            <div class="table-wrap m-t-lg">
                                                                            <table class="table table-hover table-fixed m-t-sm" id="tableindex">
                                                                                <thead>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <th class="col-xs-4 border-left">Month &amp; year</th>
                                                                                        <th class="col-xs-4">Numerator</th>
                                                                                        <th class="col-xs-4 border-right">Denominator</th>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </thead>
                                                                                <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
                                                                            </table>
                                                                        </div>
```

Comment: Code, or examples ? The question seems vague

Comment: you need to give us something to begin with. I f you need to discuss something, please join chat room for that

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer replacing the contents of table every-time I refresh the table via click.
On click of Table, fetch data via Ajax and process it in HTML format
replace original data content with new processed data and be done with that

Comment: I am not giving you code since you already have done it (reference to Ist part of your question)

Comment: Code posted.Can you now give suggestion. As Its working fine in some pages as well.@ahmednawazbutt